# Declare a static variable in a foreach in PHP

Tags: php, static, for-loop, foreach, scope

i have a very simple question. How can i make this code

```
$i = 0;
foreach($Array as $Value)
{

    echo $i;
    $i++
}
```

but written like this?

```
foreach($Array as $Value)
{
    $i = 0;
    echo $i;
    $i++
}
```

should i use a STATIC variable? or what? I don't have a clear view on this.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What is the expected output of your script?

Comment: Why do you want to declare `$i` inside the loop?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your second example will always echo "0" because you are resetting the value on each iteration.  Why would you do this?

Comment: $i must be created in the foreach and die when the foreach is completed

Comment: @Empeus: Why?  What output do you want?  What are you trying to do?  That's not how `foreach`es work.  If you don't want `$i` to exist after the loop, just `unset($i)` after the loop is done.

Comment: i did that, but i don't think is right ...

Comment: @Empeus: What do you mean "don't think it's right"?

Comment: If i'm understanding this right, this is just a scope issue? You don't want $i to interfere with a previously set $i? (i.e. don't want its value overwritten - just want to use it for the purpose of the loop and then continue)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't really do that. static variables are used to persist a variable's value between invocations of the function they're embedded in. They're not useful for a simple loop. Your second code will simply reset the counter to zero on every iteration.

e.g. this is a correct usage:

```
function count() {
   static $x = 0; // executed the first time count() is called, then never again"
   echo ++$x;
}
count(); // 1
count(); // 2
count(); // 3
```

You can certainly have

```
foreach($array as $val) {
   static $x = 0;
   echo ++$x;
}
```

but you don't gain anything, since that particular piece of code never goes out of scope for the duration of the loop, so $x's value would never get "lost".

Comment: $i must be created in the foreach and die when the foreach is completed

Comment: then declare $i outside the loop as you are, and unset it after the loop. you cannot have it auto-die within the loop, because PHP's variable scope is function-level, not statement-level.

Answer (score 1):

you may want use

```
foreach($Array as $i => $Value)
{
    echo $i;    
}
```

or

```
foreach(array_values($Array) as $i=>$Value)
{

    echo $i;
}
```

While first your example is correct, too

Comment: $i must be created in the foreach and die when the foreach is completed –

Comment: @Empeus, ok you may unset it after foreach loop, but usually people don't do it. It's created in foreach here